# Como sumar celdas fila por fila en un datatable

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables, laravel-blade

actualmente estoy intentando hacer un calculo de saldos en una tabla cuyos datos vienen de una BD
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito hacer que en la columna saldo se vayan sumando las cantidad de compra y restando las de devolución, y que se realice esta operacion por cliente

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="tb_productos">
            <thead class="bg-info">
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Cliente</th>
                <th>Cantidad Compra</th>
                <th>Cantidad Devolución</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Saldo</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($clientes as $cliente)
            <tr class="table-light">
                <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
                <td>{{$cliente->Nombres}} {{$cliente->Apellido}}</td>
                <td id="cantidad_rc">{{$cliente->Cantidad}}</td>
                <td id="cantidad_dev_rc">{{$cliente->Cantidad_dev}}</td>
                <td>{{$cliente->fecha}}</td>
                <td id="saldo"></td>
            </tr>
            
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Este es código que tengo en la vista.

Prácticamente necesito hacer un Kardex, algo similar a esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probaste algo así?: `<td id="saldo">{{ $cliente->Cantidad - $cliente->Cantidad_dev }}</td>`

Comment: Si, pero me suma solo la fila, necesito esa operación N cantidad de veces, en donde el cliente sea el mismo, es decir, compra 4 en x fecha luego en otra fecha devuelve, necesito que esas cantidades se resten.

Comment: Si la operación la haces dentro del ciclo foreach no tiene por que hacerlo en una sola fila, por otro lado ¿por qué no calculas directo esto en la consulta y en la vista solo pintar los datos?

Comment: por qué hacer eso desde la vista si lo puedes hacer desde el controlador? lo digo para que tu vista no quede con tanto proceso de php...